# My ajax call to node script not working

Tags: node.js, ajax, firebase-hosting

**servercode.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get("/abc",function(req, res) {
    res.send("Hello");  
});
```

**clientcode.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
            $.get("/abc", function(string) {
                 alert(string);
            })
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    There is no as such body of this. Its just works. :)    
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to call the servercode.js script from my client. Both files are on the node server. So that I receive the alert Hello in my client. 
Though my main aim is to call a function periodically that would be written in servercode.js file. But for the time being I am not even being able to receive the hello response from the server and my files are in firebase hosting.
I hope I am clear with my question.
Help me on this!! Thank you very much.

Comment: do you open the html file over http or the filesystem? do you have a [app.listen](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen)? do you see the request in the devtool-network tab after refreshing?

Comment: That's all what i have written as code.

Comment: i don't know about firebase but your app needs to listen to some port, and you can serve the static files on the same port by using express.static

Comment: What are you using at command line to start your server? You also definitely need an `app.listen(80)` if you're trying to get an AJAX request back on the default port.